# Warnings with base_link in namespace for robot_localization

Tags: ros, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

```
<group if="$(arg enable_ekf)" > 
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization"  >
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg ekf_yaml_path)" />
    <param name="map_frame"       value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame"      value="$(arg ns)/odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="$(arg ns)/base_link"/>
    <param name="world_frame"     value="$(arg ns)/odom"/>
  </node>
</group>
```

The above are the relevant lines in my launch file, but when I try it to run it, there are warnings thrown and the functionality is not as expected. The warnings are as below:

**[WARN] [1617652671.519795535,
1553.900000000]: Could not obtain transform from base_link to jackal2/base_link. Error was "base_link" passed to
lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.

[ WARN] [1617652673.364580966, 1555.740000000]: Could not obtain transform from base_link to  jackal1/base_link. Error was
"base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.**

I don't understand why these would come up since I am specifically assigning a base_link_frame. Why does it matter if "base_link" exists or not?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375480/warnings-with-base_link-in-namespace-for-robot_localization/) by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-06**:
It shouldn't matter what you name it as long as everything is consistent.  Do any of your sensor messages reference `base_link`?

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2021-04-06**:
Looks like the velocity controller which is used by the ekf sends 'odom' with 'base_link' header, instead of robot_namespace/base_link.
Any idea how I could correct this?

Below is how I spawn the controllers.

`<node name="controller\_spawner" pkg="controller\_manager" type="spawner" args="jackal\_joint\_publisher jackal\_velocity\_controller" />`

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-04-06**:
Can you please try this -

`<node name="controller\_spawner" pkg="controller\_manager" type="spawner" args="jackal\_joint\_publisher jackal\_velocity\_controller" ns="$(arg ns)" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the Jackal uses `diff_drive_controller` as the `jackal_velocity_controller` (see [jackal_control/config/control.yaml](https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/melodic-devel/jackal_control/config/control.yaml#L5)).  Your name looks slightly different, so please confirm this is correct for your setup.  If it is, you can set the `base_frame_id` parameter in the controller configuration as mentioned in the [`diff_drive_controller` documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller#Parameters):

> `base_frame_id` (string, default: base_link)
> Base frame_id, which is used to fill in the child_frame_id of the Odometry messages and TF.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2021-04-06**:
Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. But it seems that my IMU publishes to 'base_link' rather than 'jackalx/base_link'. Do you know where I can change that?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-06**:
That's likely a parameter in the IMU driver itself.  I took a quick look and didn't see where that would be configured.  I thought it would be in `jackal_base/launch/base.launch` ([link](https://github.com/jackal/jackal_robot/blob/melodic-devel/jackal_base/launch/base.launch)), but I don't see the publisher of `/imu/data_raw` there.  For simulations, the Jackal uses the [IMU from `hector_gazebo_plugins`](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins#GazeboRosImu) ([see `jackal_description/urdf/jackal.gazebo`])(https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/3b07ca0c1cba1856d0774923d28b6790a3fbdd6d/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.gazebo#L10)).  Sorry, I can't help more with that.

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2021-04-06**:
Yeah, I saw that it was in the jackal.gazebo file, but there seems to be no similar parameter there where I can specify the base_frameID. Thank you for your help anyway. Maybe I can write another node to republish this data to the correct frames

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-06**:
I'm not familiar enough with Jackals to know if they are set up to handle [namespaces](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) and/or `tf_prefix` properly, but this seems like the kind of situation where they would be helpful.

Another (hacky) option would be to use a [`topic_tools/transform` node](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform) and manually change the frame_id.

**Comment by [pointsnadpixels](https://answers.ros.org/users/33199/pointsnadpixels/) on 2021-04-06**:
Thanks again, for your help. If I mention a frame ID in the `jackal_description/urdf/jackal.gazebo` file, it does change the IMU frame ID published messages. Do you have any idea how I can pass that as a parameter to the jackal.gazebo file?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-06**:
You can use [arguments in `xacro`](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Rospack_commands) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot>
  <xacro:arg name="imu_body" default="imu_link" />
  ...
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="imu_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
      ...
      <bodyName>$(arg imu_body)</bodyName>
      ...
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  ...
</robot>
```

Then you can use it in a launch file like this:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro path/to/model.urdf.xacro imu_body:=different_link" />
```

I didn't actually try this with the Jackal code, so there may be some extra steps (e.g., propagating the argument through includes if necessary).  Note that you could implement `different_link` as an argument from the launch file, too.